# Change variable bounds in a pyomo model

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

I use the command

`var.setlb(var.bounds[0] - 1/2)`

to subtract `0.5` from the lower bound of a pyomo variable `var` and to update the bound to that value.

For variables whose domain is Integer this works exactly as I would have expected: The private variable `_lb` changes, and so does the variable `bounds[0]`.

For variables whose domain is Binary, this results in the private variable `_lb` changing to `-0.5`, but the variable `bounds[0]` remains untouched. I assume that this is intentionally done because Binary variables are (in some sense) supposed to remain binary. However, having stored different values as bounds for a variable seems to be confusing.

It is the private variable that appears to matter for the solver (which is what I want), but I also need to retrieve the updated bound later in my code, which is problematic.

Is there was a "more radical way" to change the bounds of a variable?

Comment: to be honest there should not be any lower or upper bound for binary variables? I mean it is either False or True (0 or 1) so in every case binary variables should have a lower bound of 0 and upper bound of 1... Why would you want to change the bounds of a binary variable I don't really get it

Comment: I am interested in a (modified) continuous relaxation of the problem. Here, the bounds indeed matter. If you are interested in the details, you are more than welcome to have a look [at this paper](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_HTML/2018/11/6947.html).

Comment: What is a "more radical way" to change the bounds of a variable? And I hate to be the guy who asks this inevitable question, instead of using binary, what's preventing you from using integers variables that are bounded between 0 and 1?

Comment: Probably I should have clarified this before: I am testing an algorithm that gets as input a mixed-integer nonlinear pyomo model and computes a feasible point by looking at modified relaxations. Hence, I don't have control over the way the model is written and I want my code to be as robust as possible.

In my view, a "more radical way" for changing the bounds would imply that both, public and private variables get changed. 

Maybe (as you pointed out) changing the domain of the variable does the job. So thanks for your comment.

Comment: I would say that this is a very interesting question. However, and I am no expert about the inner components of a `Var` object, I suspect that Pyomo's binary variables have a failsafe that might prevent regular users from attempting to do mathematically incoherent actions (like setting other bounds than [0,1] on a binary variable while keeping a binary domain), or that it is just not designed to do this.